# Reverse string comparison using C

Tags: c

I just compiled this program but it doesn't seem to work.

What I'm supposed to do is make a program that determine if a word is a palindrome (a word that is the same forward and backward, for example "racecar" or "eye").

It also should ignore case letters (for example Racecar or eYe). This is what I have so far:

```
int main()

    char word[21],reverse[21];
    printf("Type a word and I will tell you if it is a Palindrome: ");
    fgets(word,21,stdin);
    puts("");
    printf("The word that you typed is: %s \n",word);
    strcpy(reverse,word);
    strrev(reverse);
    if((strcmp(reverse,word))==0)
    printf("This word is a palindrome");
    else
    printf("This word is NOT a palindrome");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cool, so does your program work?

Comment: So whats the issue? You mentioned doesn't seem to work why is that? an error? wrong output?

Comment: "it doesn't work" - the problem description of champions

Comment: I would recommend looking up the function strcmpi.  That might be helpful to you.

Comment: `fgets` will read in the newline character at the end of the input. You need to chomp off the newline character otherwise it will never be a palindrome.

Comment: @Glenn: It isn't clear that the program is running on Windows, which is where [`strcmpi()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235392.aspx) is almost native — though the MS manual page says (incorrectly) that it's a POSIX function name and you should use `_stricmp()` instead).  On POSIX, the analogue is [`strcasecmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcasecmp.html).

Comment: Problem solved, thank you for the help. The issue was here if((strcmp(reverse,word))==0). Comparing the 2 strings if they were equal it was supposed to return 0 but it wasn't.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need reverse the string to check if it is a palindrome, also `strrev` is not a function in the C standard. You could just check in place from the beginning and end of the word:

```
char word[21];
printf("Type a word and I will tell you if it is a Palindrome: ");
fscanf(stdin, "%s", word);
puts("");
printf("The word that you typed is: %s \n",word);

size_t len = strlen(word);
int s;
bool palindrome = true;
for (s = 0; s < len / 2; s++) {
    if (tolower(word[s]) != tolower(word[len-1-s])) {
        palindrome = false;
        break;
    }
}
if(palindrome)
    printf("This word is a palindrome");
else
    printf("This word is NOT a palindrome");
```

This saves in terms of both space and time.

Answer (score 2):

`fgets()` stores the linefeed character into the supplied buffer if it encounters one. When you type in a word and press enter, the “enter” produces a linefeed character, and this is being stored in your buffer. When you reverse the string, the linefeed character will be part of that reversal, and as a result, you will never get a positive result. Additionally, in order to make sure that comparisons can be done case-insensitively, you can convert the entire word to lowercase (or uppercase) first.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char word[21] = {0}, reverse[21];

    printf("Type a word and I will tell you if it is a Palindrome: ");
    fgets(word,21,stdin);

    // remove linefeed character if there is one
    size_t len = strlen(word);
    if (len > 0 && word[len - 1] == '\n')
    {
        word[len - 1] = '\0';
        len--;
    }

    // convert string to lowercase
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        word[i] = tolower(word[i]);

    puts("");
    printf("The word that you typed is: %s \n",word);

    strcpy(reverse,word);
    strrev(reverse);

    if((strcmp(reverse,word))==0)
        printf("This word is a palindrome");
    else
        printf("This word is NOT a palindrome");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Test the result of `fgets()`?  I like `word[strcspn(word, "\n")] = '\0';` as a single-line way of safely deleting the newline if it is present and overwriting the null byte with another null byte if there is none.  It only assumes that `word` is a null-terminated string.

Comment: I prefer the `strlen` way. Often you need the length for other purposes anyway.

Comment: And at the point where you need the length, the POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) function begins to score since it tells you the length exactly.  But you're right; if you need the length, then `strcspn()` isn't a benefit.

Comment: Great guys, Thank you all very much for the information. As I saw there are many ways to fix the problem but I would like not to change a lot the way I did it, so particular thanks to @dreamlax

Answer (score 0):

- Try this simple code  :

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <string.h>
>
> int main()
> {
>     char word[21] = {0}, reverse[21] = {0};
>     int len;
>     printf("Type a word and I will tell you if it is a Palindrome: ");
>     fgets(word,21,stdin);
>
>      len = strlen(word);
>
>     // convert string to lowercase and remove '\n' feed problem if any
>     for (int i = 0; i < len ; i++)
>      {
>      if(word[i] != '\n')
>      word[i] = tolower(word[i]);
>      }
>      word[i] = '\0';
>
>     puts("");
>     printf("The word that you typed is: %s \n",word);
>
>     strcpy(reverse,word);
>     strrev(reverse);
>
>     if((strcmp(reverse,word))==0)
>         printf("This word is a palindrome");
>     else
>         printf("This word is NOT a palindrome");
>
>     return 0;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

fgets, also puts \n at the end of string.
So, correct code would be like this:

```
int main()
{

    char word[21],reverse[21];
    printf("Type a word and I will tell you if it is a Palindrome: ");
    fgets(word,21,stdin);    /// Actually it saves: "123\n"
    word[strlen(word)-1] = '\0';
    puts("");
    printf("The word that you typed is: %s \n",word);
    strcpy(reverse,word);
    strrev(reverse);
    if((strcmp(reverse,word))==0)
    printf("This word is a palindrome");
    else
    printf("This word is NOT a palindrome");

    return 0;
}
```